# Why float behave differently than other options when we give float to parent element to clear float?

Tags: css, xhtml

In this example http://jsbin.com/inoka4 no width is defined for parent element

**if i want to wrap red boxes in container border.**

then we can make this in 5 ways

- to giving `float` also to `<div class="container">`
- `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto`
- any clearfix hack to `<div class="container clearfix">`
- Giving height to `<div class="container">`
- adding one more html element (for example another `div` or `<br >`) after 2
  boxes in `<div class="container">` enter code here`and give`
  clear:left`or`:both`or`:right` to that
  element

**my question is** any other option except `float` do not make any changes in `<div class="container">` and inner boxes width. but if we use `float:left` or `right` to parent box then it's shrink the whole box and inner-boxes as well.

Why?

example link:  http://jsbin.com/inoka4

**Edit: My question is not about which method i should use, the question is why Float shrink the width**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont' use float on the container it's width is set to 100%. If you add a floating, it only takes the space it needs. In this case the width is calculated by the two divs inside.

To wrap the red boxes in the container border there is not other option except adding float to the container. The only other option would be to absolutely position all the elements but in this case you have to know the width and height of all elements in advance. So that really isn't an option.

So my advice is to use float on the container and add a clear: both on the element after the container.

Comment: "If you add a floating, it only takes the space it needs. In this case the width is calculated by the two divs inside." pls explain this more.

Comment: Letting a elements float, you make it like an element with "display: inline-block". And as an element with "inline-block" has no fixed width (like an inline element) it automatically takes only the width an height it needs for its content.

Comment: ok then why it's leaving this space http://shup.com/Shup/382470/11061222727-My-Desktop.png

Comment: Because you have set the width to 45% of the container DIV. The text in the div would take 50% of each side and that's how the width of the container div is calculated. But after that using 45% the text will wrap. The width of the container div stays the same width as it would have if the width of the inner divs are still 50%.

Answer (score 2):

I think the better option is to use overflow:hidden.  It is a simple one line change and it works.

```
div#container {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Adding extra `div`s for clear fix requires changes in html for something that is really css.  Alternatively, when using clear fix by doing hacks like...

```
div:after {
    content:....
    ...
}
```

your css just gets bigger and messier.  But it still is a good option (especially when you need to have things that overflow the box)

Reference:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/css-fudamentals-containing-children/

Comment: Wow.  I had no idea that would work.  I actually thought it would NOT work, and had to go test if for myself.  I'm off to kill most if not all of my `<div class="clear"></d>`

Comment: Glad I could help, see the new link I've added for more info

Comment: my question is why float shrink the width?

Comment: I would keep the clearing div until every browser is supporting content:after. And that will be in many years from now :(

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to always clear your floats.  Just after you close the div with class .right, and just before you close the div with class .container, add a new div like this:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

.clear is just `{clear:both;}` in your stylesheet.  That's what I use all day long, and works like a treat.

The final markup would be:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"> ... </div>
    <div class="right"> ... </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Edit:  Just like your last example, apparently.  :)

Comment: my question is why float shrink the width?